# How can I use Wi-Fi dongle as a USB wireless adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, hotspot, dongle

I have a desktop without a wireless network card running Windows XP and a Huawei-E8221 Wi-Fi dongle with a SIM card slot. My PC has Internet connection through Ethernet.

I want to use dongle as Wi-Fi hotspot so that I can use Internet on my Android phone.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

control panel>network connections>right click wireless connection>properties> click on "use windows to config my wireless network setting>click add>enter a name for your network> open> select WEP> enter a password> check “This is a computer-to-computer (ad-hoc) network; wireless access points are not used.”> click OK

Comment: connectify doesnot support XP.

Comment: sorry didnt notice XP. i edited the answer

Comment: I cannot implement your steps as my pc has no wireless network card built-in what I have is a wifi enabled usb dongle which is plug & play type so my pc  is not detecting it as wireless adapter.